# android build.xml multiple source directories

Tags: android, ant, build.xml

So I made a project with 2 source directories: one for actual code and the other for tests.
It worked well in eclipse but then I decided to start using command line and the ant tool.

Android has a built-in function of generating build.xml, so I used the command 'android update project -p ProjectName'

This build.xml for installing works fine and I can run the application on the emulator. However, it only compiles the files from my source directory and the files from my test directory are not compiled. That means that I cannot run my unit tests from the command line and if I do I get class not found exceptions.

Is there any way to include another source directory so that it would compile my unit tests as well?

This is the build.xml that was generated (the rest is comments and not added here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<project name="ProjectNameActivity" default="help">
   <property file="local.properties" />
   <property file="build.properties" />
   <property file="default.properties" />
   <path id="android.antlibs">
      <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/anttasks.jar" /> 
      <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/sdklib.jar" /> 
      <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/androidprefs.jar" /> 
   </path>
   <taskdef name="setup" classname="com.android.ant.SetupTask" classpathref="android.antlibs" /> 
   <setup /> 
</project>
```

Comment: What does the compile task look like in the xml you have (you can use edit to add it in to your question)?  Also, what directory does the test source reside under?

Comment: There is no compile task in the xml file. Or at least I did not find one. It does compile the src dir though. Tests directory is 'test'.

Comment: Sorry - I meant the javac task that compiles what's under the src dir.

Comment: I added the whole build.xml to the opening post. I does not seem to have javac either.

Comment: Have to go now... will be back in some hours.

Answer (score 0):

the ant task that compile your android program is not in the build file, it is imported.

you need to look in the `android_rules.xml` file that is imported by your `build.xml`.

There is a comment in the `build.xml` that explains how to override the imported compile ant target. Basically it instructs you to copy over the target and make the appropriate modifications.

Comment: Yes, I found some other xml file that was actually being used to do all the work. So I guess I will just try to edit that one.

Comment: @dominos  you should not edit that one since it is used for all of your projects. You should just copy the contents in to your build.xml file

Comment: Actually I decided to make a separate android test project since it seems that android is meant to be tested like that. Now both the xml-files that were generated work correctly and I can run tests.